# Rails: Virtual Model for Product on color level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am quite new to Rails and I have following problem:

In fashion we have products which have two dimensions: `color` and `size`.
Technically we have two layers

- a master product which contains colors and sizes and...
- a upc which is one specific size and color of one master product, since what you can actually purchase is a upc (color and size have to be defined).

Problem is that when you are selecting products, this is done based on the master product and color (Cool Tshirt in red) and not on master level (Cool Tshirt in red, blue, white, black...).

Now I don't really want to change that architecture, since I'd like to stick to what other connected systems are modeled after, if possible.

BUT I want to (say in the show view) show products on a master-color basis, since the user doesn't care much if the product has more available colors in the first place.

I read about Active Model, but don't exactly know what the right approach for this is and extensive research has led me nowhere...

Can somebody help me here, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I would make a table of sizes and another table of colors:  these can hold eg the name of the size (Small, Medium, etc) and any other data which is specific to each size.

Comment: Makes sense but how can I actually display the master:color options as virtual separate products then? I don't want to display just the colors that exist but rather a product with a specific color as one unit...

Comment: I fleshed out my comment into an answer.  I don't know what you mean by "virtual separate product".

Answer (score 0):

You should think about the unique concepts you're modelling:  your schema should be a reflection of the real life situation.  So, in the real situation you have the following things:

A range of colors

A range of sizes

A product line (i think this is what you mean by "master product")

A product (which is an instance of the product line with a particular color and size)

A purchase, which is of a particular product by a particular person.

```
#name
class Size

#name
class Color

#name
class ProductLine

#product_line_id, color_id, size_id
class Product
  belongs_to :product_line
  belongs_to :color
  belongs_to :size

#product_id, various other fields
class Purchase
  belongs_to :product
```

Comment: Yes but I am not creating this by scratch. I get data from other systems being ProductLines and objects which combine a particular size and color.

So do you recommend to split that up when importing?

Or if I want to stick with that data modeling concept, can I create a virtual class e.g. based on ActiveModel that pretends to be a Product but under the hood returns products on a color basis?

Comment: Your OP never said anything about importing data from some other schema.  But, if that other schema isn't a clear relational schema then you should convert it into your own good relational schema.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the [Enity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) in your models, to allow you to have dynamic attributes.

You can use an extension/gem which provides you an implementation of this pattern for ActiveRecord, check the [hydra_attribute](https://github.com/kostyantyn/hydra_attribute) gem.